# Limited App Storage?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, storage, huawei

I was trying to download a HQ TTS voice and I got the insufficient storage error. I then noticed that only about half my memory is reserved for apps only. I have 3.03GB left while only 288MB for apps? Why is there a difference? And how can I increase or change this limit so I could use more space for my applications?

Edit: when I ran DiskUsage I noticed there was such a thing as App Storage. Why is mine limited to 2 GB? I have 4GB internal and 4 GB SD card btw.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've ever partitioned a disk, you might know how one partition can fill up, even though the disk itself has plenty of space. This is one of the drawbacks to partitioning.

Well, Android partitions the disk, and then mounts the data partition onto the filesystem so that it all looks like one disk.  The data partition is usually called, confusingly, "sdcard" (the reason for the name is another story).  This partition is mounted on the directory "/mnt/sdcard".  The size is fixed by the manufacturer, and can't be easily changed.  It would require root access, and a program to resize partitions.

Recent versions of Android allow programs to store parts of themselves on the sdcard (named "extsdcard") if you have one.  I don't know why you can't use the data partition instead, but apparently you can't do it this way.

The result of all this is that without root access and knowledge of disk partitioning and the Android filesystem, there's not much you can do except delete what you don't really need.

Comment: I heard rooting voids waranty though. So i guess im stuck with 2GB of app space... Ill contact the manifacturer just in case

Comment: Good luck with that.  I kind of learned the hard way myself with my first Android device; I thought the ability to use an external SD card would give me plenty of memory, but I found out otherwise.  Next device was a 32GB LG G2.  I've got about 3.5GB of apps on it right now.